# Ctrl+B shortcuts key does not work in python 3 on robot framework

Tags: robotframework

Ctrl+B shortcuts key does not work python 3 with robot-framework-selenium library 4.0.0.
Mostly CTRL+B used to see the custom code or keyword to explore. It is used to work in previous version 3.3.1 but not in the current version

I use Pycharm IDE, Plugin --IntelliBot @SeleniumLibrary Patched, python and new version of selenium robot framework.

example keyword name: Open Browser. Please bring the cursor on top and press CTRL + B to see code under the keyword.

Comment: Please add pycharm tag.

Comment: Can you please explain more where can I add pycharm tag? does it will support to robot framework?

Comment: @asprtrmp Can I have more details please?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mac then press command+B. this will take you to the keyword origin.